# How to achieve the dom structure programmatically?

Tags: gwt

How to achieve the  following structure dynamically in GWT without using the HTMLWidget?

```
<div class="samplecheckbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
</div>
```

Comment: If you found the solution for this from the below answers, accept and upvote the answers. If you got your own answer, put that down and accept it. This will help other users who are looking answers for similar type of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

1. Create an instance of FlowPanel. (This creates the outer div)
2. Add the Checkbox to it. (This creates the checkbox to div with label embedded)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Element divElem = DOM.createDiv();
divElem.addClassName("samplecheckbox");
Element labelElem = DOM.createLabel();
Element checkElem = DOM.createInputCheck();
checkElem.setInnerText("Remember me");
labelElem.appendChild(checkElem);
divElem.appendChild(labelElem);
```